# How to join 2 match queries into a query for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to query for data that `user_id` is `'1'` and `name` is `'John'`. It's easy to write a commonly-used SQL:

```
select * from t where user_id = '1' and name = 'John';
```

But it's not easy for me to make a query for elasticsearch.

First, I made a query for `user_id`:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "user_id" : "1"
    }
  }
}
```

And the results were what I expected.

Then, I made a query for `name`:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "name" : "John"
    }
  }
}
```

It worked well, too.

But I couldn't make a query joining 2 conditions with and operation. How can I join those 2 match queries into one using and operation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is a [bool query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in which you put all your single queries:

*(I could not test the query, it might be wrong, but the bool-query is the answer to your problem)*

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [{
            "match" : {
                "user_id" : "1"
            },
            "match" : {
                "name" : "John"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi the bool query docs have moved [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: thank you. elasticsearch guys should seriously add a redirect for that