# Elasticsearch combine two different query types in one request

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to combine two query types, in my case I need a **match** and **wildcard** query, each has to operate on a different field.

The thing is, a document matches if the entity name (the document is the representation of the entity) matches the name with a wildcard at the end of the search term OR it matches if it is a exact match on one of the synonyms of the entity. Not both querys have to match, just one of them to consider the document as relevant.

Currently I need two requests to archive this:

Wildcard:

```
GET /name/type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "wildcard": {
         "name": {
            "value": "term*",
            "boost": 2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Match:

```
GET /name/type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "synonyms": "term"
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do it with one request? All my tests failed.

Comment: Have a look at the `bool` query [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363709/how-to-join-2-match-queries-into-a-query-for-elasticsearch/13363814#13363814)

Comment: With the bool query both queries have to match, in my case one of them have to match in order to consider the document as valid hit. I updated the question to point this out. Thx.

Comment: Then use `should` instead of `must`. See the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query).

Comment: I was kind of lost in the docs, I **SHOULD** read more carefully. Thank you, thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the one your are looking for..!

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/try/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value": "term*",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "synonyms": "term"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```